# Jquery tooltip desplaza el contenido de la tabla

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tengo una tabla `html` similar a esta:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-custom table-responsive">
    <thead class="ordenable">
        <tr>                                     
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_1">L</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_2">M</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_3">X</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_4">J</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_5">V</th>                    
        </tr>
    </thead>            
    <tbody> 
        <tr>                
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74
            </td>
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74
            </td>
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                75
            </td>
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                75
            </td>
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74
            </td>                       
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Y el *tooltip* lo añado asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
</script>
```

El problema es el siguiente, cuando muestro la tabla se hace de manera correcta[image: Imagen sin tooltip]

Pero cuando paso el ratón por encima para que el *tooltip* aparezca se me descolocan las columnas
[image: Imagen con tooltip]

Así se queda la tabla cuando el *tooltip* esta funcionando

```
<table class="table table-striped table-custom table-responsive">
    <thead class="ordenable">
        <tr>                                                   
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_1">L</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_2">M</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_3">X</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_4">J</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_5">V</th>                    
        </tr>
    </thead>            
    <tbody>
        <tr>                
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado." aria-describedby="tooltip106542">
                74
            </td>
            <!-- ESTA ES LA PARTE QUE CREA EL TOOLTIP -->
            <div class="tooltip fade top in" role="tooltip" id="tooltip106542" style="top: 30px; left: 866px; display: block;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">
                    El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ---------------------------------------------------- -->
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74  
            </td>
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                75  
            </td>
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                75      
            </td>
            <td class="danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74  
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por la forma en la que trabajan los tooltips de jQuery necesitarás crear un elemento `<span>` (prefiero éste por ser neutro) u otro cualquiera (como un `<div>` si quieres que sea la celda completa) en el que asignar los eventos. Si lo haces en un `<tr>` o `<th>` te creará elementos en el DOM que romperán el diseño de la tabla (no se permiten `<div>` entre `<td>` y `<td>`, por ejemplo).

**Versión con `<span>`:**

```js
$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-custom table-responsive">
    <thead class="ordenable">
        <tr>                                     
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_1">L</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_2">M</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_3">X</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_4">J</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_5">V</th>                    
        </tr>
    </thead>            
    <tbody> 
        <tr>                
            <td class="danger"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74</span>
            </td>
            <td class="danger"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74</span>
            </td>
            <td class="danger"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                75</span>
            </td>
            <td class="danger"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                75</span>
            </td>
            <td class="danger"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74</span>
            </td>                       
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Versión con `<div>`:**

```js
$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-custom table-responsive">
    <thead class="ordenable">
        <tr>                                     
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_1">L</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_2">M</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_3">X</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_4">J</th>
            <th class="col-1" id="DIAC_5">V</th>                    
        </tr>
    </thead>            
    <tbody> 
        <tr>                
            <td class="danger"><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74</div>
            </td>
            <td class="danger"><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74</div>
            </td>
            <td class="danger"><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                75</div>
            </td>
            <td class="danger"><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                75</div>
            </td>
            <td class="danger"><div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" data-original-title="El total de usuarios (incluido monitor) excede la capacidad del autobús seleccionado.">
                74</div>
            </td>                       
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Fíjate la diferencia entre ambos:

- `<span>`: El tooltip se muestra apuntando al centro del valor, pero si sacamos el ratón fuera de éste, aunque sigamos dentro de la celda, el tooltip desaparece.
- `<div>`: El tooltip se muestra apuntando al centro de la celda, y si sacamos el ratón fuera del valor pero nos mantenemos dentro de la celda el tooltip se mantiene visible.

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, un placer :)

Comment: Funciona excelente. Gracias.